# Change of basis and transformation of a vector.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, orthonormal, change-of-basis

I am given the matrix $A=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 2 & 4 \end{bmatrix}$,

and a vector  $x=\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1  \end{bmatrix}.$

After computing the eigenvalues and normalized eigenvectors, we can construct the orthonormal basis B: $B=\begin{bmatrix} \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}} & -\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}} \\ \frac{2}{\sqrt{5}} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}} \end{bmatrix}$.

How can I compute the components of x in the orthonormal basis B? Should I use
$x_{[B]} = B\cdot x$, or rather $x_{[B]} = B^{-1}\cdot x?$

I am a bit confused as to how we translate back and forth in different bases.

Comment: When you want to find components, you need to find such numbers $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$ that $\alpha_1 \textbf{v}_1 + \alpha_2 \textbf{v}_2 = \textbf{x}$. If you remember it is the same as to solve the linear system with matrix having $\textbf{v}_1$ and $\textbf{v}_2$ as columns. So $\textbf{x} = B\textbf{x}_{[B]}$

Comment: Thank you @Egor Ivanov! Much appreciated explanation.
So in order to elaborate a bit on this, is it correct to solve this algebraically like this? If $x = Bx_{[B]}$ and $B$ is invertible then $B^{-1}x=B^{-1}Bx_{[B]}$ and ultimately $B^{-1}x=x_{[B]}$

Comment: yes, exactly :)